# Regex trouble in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am trying to extract data from  a string using RegEx , but i am getting a NULL value as result.

here is my current code

```
var re = /(\[cid=(?:[0-9]*)(?:(?:,\[[^]]*\][^]]*)?|(?:,[^]]*))\])/;
var str = '[cid=5555,[CONSTIMG]5555.jpg]The Sample text is awesome';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }

}

console.log(m[0]);
```

The value that i am getting back is NULL.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to find? I can't attempt to help find a working regex if I don't know what you are looking for. Also, have you tried testing on a site like http://regexpal.com/ ?

Comment: It is because your expression does not match your input.

Comment: @David it's showing as valid here, http://postimg.org/image/egmgh1n2f/

Comment: Try this `(\[cid=\d*,(?:\[(?:.[^\]]*\]){1,2})?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression matches PCRE regular expression syntax but not JavaScript because JavaScript requires that square brackets inside a character class be escaped with `\`. This is what you want:

```
(\[cid=(?:\d*)(?:(?:,\[[^\]]*\][^\]]*)?|(?:,[^\]]*))\])
```

Explained: https://regex101.com/r/pN4vP4/2